# Update primary viewController on action in popupView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a popupView in my application using [MJPopupViewController](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController). Now, I need to update a UILabel on the main view when a button is pressed on the popupView. Either I need to update the UILabel on main view as soon the button is pressed(preferably) or when it is closed.

I have already tried viewWillDisappear and viewWillAppear methods, but both don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for calling other class Method from current class like bellow example:-

add Notification at MainClass in your `ViewDidLoad` Method:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(UpdateLable:)
                                                 name:@"UpdateLbl"
                                               object:nil];


    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)UpdateLable:(NSNotification *)notification {

   //Update lable code here
}
```

Now you just need to call this method From your `popupView` class Button click Action for calling update Notification

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateLbl" object:self]
```

;

Hope it's Helps you:)